# Pandas column not displaying when using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that I've imported as a Pandas DataFrame. I've converted one of the columns 'talkTime' ,which is represented in seconds (an integer), to a duration representation on the same value. This seems to work fine and I can see that the new column, Duration(h:m:s),  has been added to the original DF.

The problem i'm having is that when I call the groupby function on the modified DF (including the Duration column) the duration column does not show up in the resulting table.

The original DF looks like so:

```
print(df.head())
                dateOn             sipCallId  ...      item     talkTime        costCentre
0  2021-08-16 04:08:19                  Id-1  ...    Item-1          111     Cost Centre-1
1  2021-08-16 04:52:35                  Id-2  ...    Item-3          203     Cost Centre-1
2  2021-08-16 04:59:22                  Id-3  ...    Item-1           84     Cost Centre-1
3  2021-08-16 05:31:41                  Id-4  ...    Item-2          704     Cost Centre-1
4  2021-08-16 05:35:23                  Id-5  ...    Item-1          304     Cost Centre-1
```

I then added the Duration(h:m:s) column using the below:

`df["Duration(h:m:s)"] = pd.to_datetime(df["talkTime"], unit='s').dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

This is then added to the original DF

```
print(df.head())
                dateOn   sipCallId  ...      item     talkTime        costCentre  Duration(h:m:s)
0  2021-08-16 04:08:19        Id-1  ...    Item-1           20     Cost Centre-1         00:00:20     
1  2021-08-16 04:52:35        Id-2  ...    Item-3           33     Cost Centre-1         00:00:33
2  2021-08-16 04:59:22        Id-3  ...    Item-1           84     Cost Centre-1         00:01:24
3  2021-08-16 05:31:41        Id-4  ...    Item-2           45     Cost Centre-1         00:00:45
4  2021-08-16 05:35:23        Id-5  ...    Item-1           65     Cost Centre-1         00:01:05
```

From here I call the groupby function to group the data in the following manner:

```
breakdown = df.groupby('costCentre').apply(lambda sub: sub.pivot_table(
    index=['agentname'],
    values=['cost','talkTime', 'Duration(h:m:s)'],
    aggfunc= sum,
    margins=True,
    margins_name='Sub-Total',
))
```

The result does not include the Duration field though.

```
print(breakdown.head())
                                             cost  talkTime
costCentre              agentname
Cost Centre-1           Person 1             0.38       111
                        Person 2             0.68       203
                        Person 3             0.34        84
                        Person 4             2.35       704
                        Person 5             1.32       314
```

Sample data including all columns:

```
print(df.head().to_dict())
{'dateOn': {0: '2021-08-16 04:08:19', 1: '2021-08-16 04:52:35', 2: '2021-08-16 04:59:22', 3: '2021-08-16 05:31:41', 4: '2021-08-16 05:35:23'}, 'sipCallId': {0: 'Id-1', 1: 'Id-2', 2: 'Id-3', 3: 'Id-4', 4: 'Id-5'}, 'agentname': 
{0: 'Person-1', 1: 'Person-2', 2: 'Person-3', 3: 'Person-4', 4: 'Person-5'}, 'callerId': {0: '0123456789', 1: '0123456789', 2: '0123456789', 3: '0123456789', 4: '0123456789'}, 'talkTime': {0: 155, 1: 199, 2: 109, 3: 29, 4: 1}, 'cost': {0: 0.65, 1: 0.83, 2: 0.45, 3: 0.12, 4: 
0.0}, 'item': {0: 'Item-1', 1: 'Item-1', 2: 'Item-1', 3: 'Item-2', 4: 'Item-3'}, 'costCentre': {0: 'Cost Centre-1', 1: 'Cost Centre-1', 2: 'Cost Centre-3', 3: 'Cost Centre-4', 4: 'Cost Centre-3'}, 'Duration(h:m:s)': {0: '00:02:35', 1: '00:03:19', 2: '00:01:49', 3: '00:00:29', 4: '00:00:01'}}
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Please provide the sample of data including all the columns you are using  in above code. The above data is missing columns like `agentname`, `cost`, etc. You can use `df.head().to_dict()`, and the terminal output to the question.

Comment: @ThePyGuy, post updated as requested. Do you think the issue is that the duration field is represended as string values? Maybe I can add an additional _talkTime_ field to the groupby table and do the conversion afterwards? Is that perhaps possible?

Comment: The problem is, you are applying aggregate as `sum`, but the Duration column is string type

Comment: Yeah...saw that when I called .to_dict() as you suggested.  Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to be able to do numeric operations on 'Duration' it has to be numeric or datetime. So don't do the `.dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` conversion, that converts it back to a formatted string, which cannot be aggregated.

Comment: And if there is string type column as well, I'm not sure if you can calculate the grand total i.e. the marginal `sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Duration(h:m:s)` column is not a numeric type, `sum` can not be applied on it, and even if you use `first` as aggregate for duration column `{`Duration(h:m:s)`:'first'}`, you will again get error for marginal sum, because its string type.

What you can do is, first get the grouping result and pivot only for the numeric columns, then later concatenate other string type columns, setting the proper indices.

```py
pd.concat([(df.groupby('costCentre').apply(lambda sub: sub.pivot_table(
    index=['agentname'],
    values=['cost','talkTime'],
    aggfunc= sum,
    margins=True,
    margins_name='Sub-Total',
))),df.set_index(['costCentre', 'agentname'])['Duration(h:m:s)']], axis=1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                         cost  talkTime Duration(h:m:s)
costCentre    agentname                                
Cost Centre-1 Person-1   0.65       155        00:02:35
              Person-2   0.83       199        00:03:19
              Sub-Total  1.48       354             NaN
Cost Centre-3 Person-3   0.45       109        00:01:49
              Person-5   0.00         1        00:00:01
              Sub-Total  0.45       110             NaN
Cost Centre-4 Person-4   0.12        29        00:00:29
              Sub-Total  0.12        29             NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @ThePyGuy, sorry for the late reaponse. Your solution does the trick. I'm still trying to find a way to have the sub-totals included as well though. Other than that this works oerfectly.